# How to add a javascript variable to this php line?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, datepicker, date-format

I have a Javascript function which gets a date from a jQuery datepicker.

Now i want to print this selected date in this format.

```
$selecteddate = strftime('%A').date("(d-n-Y)");
```

How can i add this date, which is a javascript variable to this php format?
Because I would like to echo $selecteddate later on..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what means "later on", in another request? If you want to pass javascript variable to php you need send request to server, if you want simple output javascript variable (date object) in date format you don't need server side at all

Comment: You might want to look into AJAX for this.

Comment: I did it with AJAX, thanks for the 'push'.
`$datum = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['datum']);
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL');
$selecteddate = strftime('%A', strtotime($datum)).date(" (d-n-Y)", strtotime($datum));`

Basicly send the date, formatted and printed there. Thanksss!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$datum = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['datum']); 
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL'); 
$selecteddate = strftime('%A', strtotime($datum)).date(" (d-n-Y)", strtotime($datum));
```

Basicly send the date, formatted and printed there. Thanksss!

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery DatePicker widget has a [dateformatter utility function](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate). Could you use that instead of going into PHP and back?